# Turtlebot Arm Installation / Catkin Error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Another one I've been faffing about trying to figure out why I can't get it to compile / make.

Anyway, I have been trying to install the Turtlebot Arm package from fergs

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm

Admittedly on Hydro ros, and I keep getting an error during catkin_make.

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot_block_manipulation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_block_manipulation)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl" with any of
  the following names:

    pclConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pcl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "pcl_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "pcl" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_block_manipulation/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Now i've tried a number of things like git cloning various pcl's or pcl-1.7s into catkin_ws/src and making them but it has no effect.

From what I can tell the original hydro-desktop install has both pcl and pcl-1.7 folders, and within pcl-1.7 is a PCLconfig.cmake file, it just seems to not be found or have no effect.

Anyone have a good idea of what to do next?

Any help is appreciated as I'm a bit lost on this one

Cdr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76916/turtlebot-arm-installation-/-catkin-error/) by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In hydro you need to use the new pcl rosep rules (`libpcl-all` and `libpcl-all-dev`). Since that package already depends on `pcl_ros` it is probably easiest to just remove a direct dependency on `pcl`, in these three places:

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm/blob/groovy-devel/turtlebot_block_manipulation/package.xml#L19

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm/blob/groovy-devel/turtlebot_block_manipulation/package.xml#L27

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm/blob/groovy-devel/turtlebot_block_manipulation/CMakeLists.txt#L5

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-09-06**:
Thanks this has worked, I also needed to repeat the same process for the package turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration. I'm not sure if this will have any unknown effects but I guess I will find out :)

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-09-20**:
Note that not all these packages actually work -- I never got around to making calibration or demos work, I only got as far as moveit integration updates, which are now I believe out of date given changes to the kinematics plugin format.

**Comment by [cdrwolfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/5809/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-09-23**:
ok, thanks fergs. I've been looking at this and the clam packages just to get a better idea of the pick and place stuff, and different kinds of ros control / communication